# Передать массив как параметр в процедуру Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

Есть метод который принимает массив ID, и этот ID через цикл передаю в хранимую процедуру Oracle и возвращаю записи из базы, но я хочу написать такую процедуру которая будет принимать массив всех ID и возвращать данные из базы данных. Как это сделать?

```cs
public async Task GetAccounts(long[] request)
{
    request = new long[] { 50000347, 50000347 };
    
    foreach (long id in request)
    {
        IEnumerable<BasicAccountData> result = await _accountRepository.GetBasicAccounts(id);
        result.ToList().ForEach(x => response.Add(new BasicAccount()
        {
            AccountProduct = x.PRODUCTID,
            AccountName = x.NAME,
            Currency = x.CURRENCY,
            Iban = x.IBAN,
            Id = x.ID
        }));
    }
}
```

```sql
PROCEDURE GET_BASIC_ACCOUNTS(ACCOUNT_ID IN VARCHAR2, O_RESULT   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
  BEGIN
    OPEN O_RESULT FOR
      SELECT T.ID, B.IBAN, F.CURRENCY,
             T.NAMEACCOUNT NAME, DEX.PRODUCTID PRODUCTID
        FROM RSBANK.DACCOUNT_DBT T
        LEFT JOIN RSBANK.DACCOUNT_DBT_EXTEND DEX
        ON DEX.ACCOUNT = T.ACCOUNT
        WHERE T.ACCID = ACCOUNT_ID;
  END;
```

```cs
   

    public static Task<IEnumerable<TData>> ReaderDyn<TData>(this IDbConnection db, string procedureName, object data)
    {
         return db.QueryAsync<TData>(procedureName, data, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: commandTimeout);
    }
         public async Task<IEnumerable<Data>> GetBasicAccounts(long[] accId)
    {
          //long[] ACCOUNT_ID = { 4,31, 12, 56 };
          await using OracleConnection db = GetOracleConnection(DbConnectionEnum.RSLB);
          return await db.ReaderDyn<Data>(DbNameStore.Oracle.HSD.HGRSA.GET_BASIC_ACCOUNTS, new { ACCOUNT_ID = accId });
    }
```

Comment: [Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) - как использовать в C# ADO.NET.

Comment: Этот вопрос следует разбить на два: первый - как сделать хранимку в Oracle (ответ уже получен), второй - как вызывать её из C# (и указать, что используется: сырой ADO.NET, Dapper, что-то ещё?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Oracle необходимо создать отдельный тип данных, который будет представлять из себя коллекцию - таблицу из чисел.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE numbersID AS TABLE OF number;
```

Единственное, в коде у вас пример с **числами**, а процедура ожидает **varchar2**. Тут надо вам определиться с типами данных. И если все таки это varchar2, то поменять тип данных на вот такой(к примеру)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE numbersID AS TABLE OF varchar2(50);
```

В процедуре меняем тип параметра ACCOUNT_ID на наш созданный тип numbersID. Так же в условиях меняем = на in (select *...)

```
PROCEDURE GET_BASIC_ACCOUNTS(ACCOUNT_ID IN numbersID, O_RESULT   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
  BEGIN
    OPEN O_RESULT FOR
      SELECT T.ID, B.IBAN, F.CURRENCY,
              T.NAMEACCOUNT NAME, DEX.PRODUCTID PRODUCTID
      FROM RSBANK.DACCOUNT_DBT T
      LEFT JOIN RSBANK.DACCOUNT_DBT_EXTEND DEX
           ON DEX.ACCOUNT = T.ACCOUNT
      WHERE T.ACCID in (select COLUMN_VALUE from table(ACCOUNT_ID)); -- Выбираем все переданные данные
  END;
```

Остается только из приложения передать массив данных. Именно массив, а не объект.

Comment: вот так передаю массив long[] id = { 12, 23 };  в процедуру , но возврашаеться всегда 0 записей. Все сделал так как у вас в примере

Comment: @Saba'sPage Надо смотреть на стороне БД, что приходит в переменную. Есть подозрение, что массив передается пустой. Так же вызовите процедуру вручную и дайте на вход массив из ID, которые у вас есть в таблице, должны получить правильный результат.

Comment: вот щас пишет "OCI-22303: type \"HUR\".\"NUMBERSID\" not found", но я знаю что он сушествует

Comment: Oracle считает иначе. Ваш тип должен быть создан в той же схеме, что и процедура GET_BASIC_ACCOUNTS(Судя по ошибке это HUR, во всяком случае Oracle именно там пытается его найти). Проверьте так же имена(на всякий)

Comment: Я  добавил код , там где я вызываю БД , можете посмотреть что там не так ?

Comment: @Saba'sPage - нужно использовать `DataTable` в качестве параметра.

Comment: @Saba'sPage Я бы вам рекомендовал оформить это отдельным постом с указанием библиотек, которые вы используете для общения с Oracle, а так же, в идеале, какие значения передаются, какие приходят в Oracle.